# DDR3 not detected at my new Asus transformer Laptop TP500LN

Tags: laptop, memory

I just bought a new Asus transformer Laptop TP500LN (the version which have 840m GPU), the laptop came with a 4 GB DDR3 RAM. When I opened it , I have found that the RAM is attached to the motherboard and there is an empty socket which can hold another 8GB DDR3 ram as shown at the following Pic.

So I took my other two old working DDR3 Rams from my old Laptop (Dell Inspiron n5010) to try them, but both didn't work at the Asus TP500LN , the BIOS just read the 4 GB RAM, the first ram was Kingston 2GB DDR3 RAM as shown at the following pic, the other was Samsung 2GB DDR3 and both work together well at the Dell Laptop .

[image: Motherboard and RAM]

I know the Build-in ram is DDR3L 1600(O.C.) MHz SDRAM as specified at the Asus site [here](http://www.asus.com/2-in-1-PCs/ASUS_Transformer_Book_Flip_TP500LN/specifications/) and my old RAMs are DDR3-1333 with a lower speed, but I read that they can work together at the lowest speed of them. So is my Socket corrupted? Or its a compatibility problem? If the second one, what options have I to buy to increase my memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.ultrabookreview.com/4879-upgrade-memory-asus-vivobook-transformer-book-flip/) indicates that your laptop requires low-voltage SO-DIMMs. The memory you've tried to add requires 1.5 V compared to low-voltage RAM which typically require 1.35 V or 1.25 V. Quoting the article, "You have to get low voltage ram – otherwise it won’t work".

Comment: I can Confirm that (Team Group Team-Elite-1600 DDR3L 1.35v ) is working for the TP500LN Laptop .